Restrict rights for Azure Automation Managed Identity
I'm building an Azure Automation runbook that sends guest invitations via Graph API using a system managed identity for authentication. I have configured the MI enterprise application with the following Graph permission: User.Invite.All (for sending invitations), User.ReadWrite.All (apparently needed for redemption).
My MI has the following  Azure roles: Automation Job Operator, Automation Runbook Operator.
In this configuration, my runbook sends invitations successfully, but no guest users are created when the invitation link is redeemed.
If I then add the User Access Administrator role to my MI, everything works flawlessly. However, this seems a bit overkill to me, as this role can do much more than what is needed to complete the task (guest user creation). Is there a way I can accomplish this with a more restrictive approach?
